# CSS column-count bug break Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, styles

I assigned a column-count:2 to a div, but when I test the responsive to the browser (Google Chrome version 108.0.5359.99), it breaks and I need to use the tasks manager to close the window.

Is the column-count because when I comment that style line the browser works fine, and in Firefox column-count works.

Any idea or alternative to column count?

Comment: Please show us the code which breaks, and please describe in more detail what is not working. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry, but I can't show the code because is confidential to the job.

Comment: You can extract just enough to demonstrate the problem, it doesn’t need to show any confidential information.